# js shorthand if/else within echo

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong here?  No matter what the value of `response.count` it always outputs the second condition... 'entries have'.  I am familiar with doing this in php, but either I am overlooking something or it is different in js.

`response.count` is returning correct values...

```
if (response.success)
{
    // show success message
    $("#dtAlert").html('Success! \'<b>'+response.count+'</b>\' selected '+(response.count === 1 ? 'entry has' : 'entries have')+' been deleted from your account.');        
}
```

Comment: What is the `typeof response.count`?

Comment: I return the count of an array... count($array) stored in an array with json_encode($ajax_result).  Soo, int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the result 1 or "1"? The `===` operator compares the type of value. Try to change to `==`.
See working here: http://jsfiddle.net/aLh4s/

Comment: I tried that as well... still doesn't work.  For instance in the console my response was `{"count":1,"success":true}` yet it still shows 'entries have'.

Comment: Yeah, I get it... it is just not working... there has to be something else going on.  The funny thing is the first part of my output it always returns the correct number yet the condition right after it never performs correctly.

Comment: Marking this as correct, but the actual problem appears to have been something with my app... restarted and uploaded the file and it is good to go.  Must not have been uploading the file even though it said it was?  :dunno: